# Efficient Script to unlink duplicate object

Tags: python, geometry

Is there an efficient way to unlink geometry? I use a loop on object data user then duplicate:

[image]

I use loop on object data user then duplicate :

```
if obj.type == "MESH" and obj.data.users > 1 and  obj.name != obj.data.name:
        bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=False)
        obj.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

but it's so slow. Can we just unlink all geometries with a built-in function?

Regards, Gilles

Answer (score 3):

This should be way faster. Operators force a recalculation of the entire dependency graph once executed. I use a copy of `bpy.data.objects` so as not to modify the objects while iterating over the list of objects.

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects[:]:
    if obj.type == "MESH" and obj.data.name != obj.name and obj.data.users > 1:
        obj.data = obj.data.copy()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, I have to mention that the menu *Object ► Relations ► Make Single User* have multiple operators for that. The one you could use is *Object & Data*.

[image]

The python command is [`bpy.ops.object.make_single_user(obdata=True)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.make_single_user).

It would be interesting to compare the execution time with @Gorgious's script. But I reckon if that's all you need to do, it's enough.

Comment: Haha I didn't even consider doing that :) After a short test with circa 15k cubes both take more or less the same time (a few seconds). I'd still go with yours since it's more straightforward for such a basic use case.

Comment: Good to know both are viable! Funny your edit, as right after posting I thought "*oh wait, I could have added the python command... Oh well, it's time to cook lunch and I have python tooltips on my screenshot*". Well played x)